# Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined in App.js:1

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

This error in my react project pointing out at :

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
```

What I am doing wrong? 
I am using the react v15.0.2.

Note: I am following cory house course for react and redux application.

I am unable to solve this error out from two days.

Comment: I would do a view source on your application to make sure all your script dependencies are resolving.

Comment: Thank you Judson for your respose. I figured it out my error, its silly , I have used React.component instead of upper case i., React.Component while extending the class

Comment: Too funny! Welcome to the world of development! I'm an architect and I still make those mistakes!

Comment: *Thank you* Judson Terrell